apt-cacher-ng oddities
For roughly half a year now apt-cacher-ng (3.3.1-2build1, running on 20.04) has been showing strange behaviour ... 2 - 3 times a month its daily cron job expiry function fails; when one checks the status page and tries a cleanup it just randomly claims 500 errors for some repos (visiting the same URL from the same machine using curl works just fine).
And often it gets stuck on a particular URL (as I write it has been sitting on Downloading security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease... for half an hour for no apparent reason.
I have tried to rule out IPv6 issues by forcing both apt and apt-cacher-ng to use IPv4 only w/ no change.
Has anyone experienced similar issues, or, even better, managed to fix them?

I have definitely seen the issues with the cleanups from the status page; in fact, I have sworn off doing them in favor of its built-in cleanup task. I haven't had any issues downloading updates. Why are you downloading bionic security updates on focal? Maybe the issue is that bionic is EOL.

We use an apt-cacher-ng to proxy requests for machines on a private network that don't have direct access to the great unwashed. And we're paying for extended support. @OrganicMarble

Were you able to get apt-cacher-ng to cache the https esm repos? I haven't been able to get that to work. I am testing it for when 20.04 goes EOL.

That's an interesting question - I don't think anyone here  bothered checking. Will dig into this if/when I have some time to spare.
